# Remove whitespace character set from string excluding space

Tags: string, swift, whitespace

How can I remove the whitespace character set from a string but keep the single spaces between words. I would like to remove double spaces and triple spaces, etc...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

### Swift 3

```
extension String {
    func condensingWhitespace() -> String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
            .joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

let string = "  Lorem   \r  ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "
print(string.condensingWhitespace())
// Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet.
```

### Legacy Swift

`NSCharacterSet` makes this easy:

```
func condenseWhitespace(string: String) -> String {
    let components = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).filter({!isEmpty($0)})
    return join(" ", components)
}

var string = "  Lorem   \r  ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "
println(condenseWhitespace(string))
// Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet.
```

or if you'd like it as a `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    func condenseWhitespace() -> String {
        let components = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).filter({!Swift.isEmpty($0)})
        return " ".join(components)
    }
}

var string = "  Lorem   \r  ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "
println(string.condenseWhitespace())
// Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet.
```

All credit to the [NSHipster post on NSCharacterSet](http://nshipster.com/nscharacterset/).

Comment: The code for the String extension does not work with Swift 2!

Comment: For swift 3 you should use .filter({!$0.isEmpty})

Comment: There is a mismatch condenseWhitespace/condensingWhitespace in your Swift 3 code. – `CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines` can be shortened to `.whitespacesAndNewlines`.

Answer (score 11):

Swift 2 compatible code:

```
extension String {
    var removeExcessiveSpaces: String {
        let components = self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
        let filtered = components.filter({!$0.isEmpty})
        return filtered.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let str = "test  spaces    too many"
print(str.removeExcessiveSpaces)
// Output: test spaces too many
```

Answer (score 4):

#### When you have an Objective-C/Foundation background, it may seem obvious to use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(:)` with Swift in order to trim your string from its redundant whitespace characters.

The steps here are to get from your string an array of `String` where all whitespace characters have been replaced by empty strings, to filter this array into a new array of `String` where all empty strings have been removed and to join all the strings of this array into a new string while separating them by a whitespace character.

The following Playground code shows how to do it this way:

```
import Foundation

let string = "  Lorem   ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "

let newString = string
.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet())
.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
.joinWithSeparator(" ") 

print(newString) // prints "Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet."
```

If you need to repeat this operation, you can refactor your code into a `String` extension:

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    func condenseWhitespace() -> String {
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet())
            .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
            .joinWithSeparator(" ")
    }
}

let string = "  Lorem   ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "
let newString = string.condenseWhitespace()

print(newString) // prints "Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet."
```

---

#### However, with Swift, there is another way that is really functional and that does not require you to import `Foundation`.

The steps here are to get from your string an array of `String.CharacterView` where all whitespace characters have been removed, to map this array of `String.CharacterView` to an array of `String` and to join all the strings of this array into a new string while separating them by a whitespace character.

The following Playground code shows how to do it this way:

```
let string = "  Lorem   ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "

let newString = string.characters
    .split { $0 == " " }
    .map { String($0) }
    .joinWithSeparator(" ")

print(newString) // prints "Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet."
```

If you need to repeat this operation, you can refactor your code into a `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    func condenseWhitespace() -> String {
        return characters
            .split { $0 == " " }
            .map { String($0) }
            .joinWithSeparator(" ")
    }
}

let string = "  Lorem   ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "
let newString = string.condenseWhitespace()

print(newString) // prints "Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet."
```

Comment: this gets of spaces, but not tabs, or new lines, or anything else that might abstractly be defined as white space (though I'd love to see a non-Foundation solution to determining if a swift Character is a white space character)

Answer (score 0):

**For swift 3.1**

```
extension String {
    var trim : String {
        get {
            return characters
                .split { $0 == " " || $0 == "\r" }
                .map { String($0) }
                .joined(separator: " ")
        }
    }
}

let string = "  Lorem   \r  ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "
print(string.trim)
```

Will output :

```
Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use regular expression search to replace all
occurrences of one or more whitespace characters by a single space.
Example (Swift 3):

```
let string = "  Lorem   \r  ipsum dolar   sit  amet. "

let condensed = string
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
        .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

print(condensed.debugDescription) // "Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet."
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the trim() method in a Swift String extension I wrote https://bit.ly/JString.

```
var string = "hello  "
var trimmed = string.trim()
println(trimmed)// "hello"
```

Comment: I looked up your source code, but I don't think this does what the OP asked (ie, remove double and triple spaces and replace them with a single space.) If I'm wrong let me know and I'll reverse the downvote.

Comment: This removes n spaces and replaces them with no space. Exactly what the python trim method does.  To remove spaces > 1, use a regex.

Comment: But what if you have multiple spaces in middle of a string? For example, `"hello________there"` (using underscore to represent space)

Comment: the OP asked only for only removing spaces a the beginning of the string, so this answer is not correct

Comment: works also for the front. But it's cool to comment on stuff 1 year later