# Cleanest way to remove trailing blanks a string in swift?

Tags: swift

In Perl if I had trailing blanks in a string, I would use this code

`$line =~ s/ +$//;`

Is there a similar command or function in swift?

Comment: No built-in syntax, no. There are regex classes, of course. Some discussion of usage: http://benscheirman.com/2014/06/regex-in-swift/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570973/how-should-i-remove-all-the-spaces-from-a-string-swift

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797739/does-swift-has-trim-method-on-string

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I was looking more for a perl/regex kind of command.  As I have much more complicated parsing to do but this is a start.

Comment: @GAlexander Then you have to broad more your question to understanding you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift provides no support for regular expressions. It doesn't need to, though, because the only place you'll ever use Swift is in the presence of Cocoa — and Cocoa's Foundation framework *does* provide support for regular expressions (and has other string-handling commands). Swift String and Framework's NSString are bridged to one another.

Thus, you could use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` with a regular expression pattern, for example (assuming that `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` is too simple-minded for your purposes).

Comment: Good answer, this will work.  `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`

Comment: Matt alludes to a better answer for this specific case which is `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this multiple times I suggest you **add this handy extension** to your project:

```
extension String {
    var strip: String {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    }
}
```

Now you can do something **as simple as this**:

```
let line = " \t BB-8 likes Rey \t "
line.strip // => "BB-8 likes Rey"
```

---

If you prefer a **Framework** that also has some more handy features then checkout **[HandySwift](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandySwift)**. You can add it to your project **via Carthage** then use it exactly like in the example above:

```
import HandySwift    

let line = "  BB-8 likes Rey  "
line.strip // => "BB-8 likes Rey"
```