# Searching Safari For A Keyword Instead Of URL In Swift

Tags: swift, safari

Im trying to make an app that opens the safari app and searches for a specific keyword.  I know how to open Safari and search a URL, but is there any way to do it with just a keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just generate a URL with a specified keyword. Assuming you'll use Google.

Example, user searches "David Bowie"

You load this url https://www.google.com/#q=davidbowie

There are a couple good methods for removing spaces [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570973/how-should-i-remove-all-the-spaces-from-a-string-swift)