# UILabel shows more white space in top and bottom for long text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to display attributed text label inside a scrollview. I use the following code the label displays the text in centre and some extra white space is added in top and bottom.

```
NSString *STR_titl_iten_des = @"Item Description";
    NSString *STR_descrip_detail = @"Long text to be displayed";
    
    self.lbl_item_descrip.numberOfLines = 0;
    NSString *text2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",STR_titl_iten_des,STR_descrip_detail];
    
    if ([self.lbl_item_descrip respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)]) {
        NSDictionary *attribs = @{
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.lbl_item_descrip.textColor,
                                  NSFontAttributeName: self.lbl_item_descrip.font
                                  };
        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText =
        [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text2
                                               attributes:attribs];
        NSRange cmp = [text2 rangeOfString:STR_titl_iten_des];
        if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
        {
            [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:21.0]}
                                    range:cmp];
        }
        else
        {
            [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17.0]}
                                    range:cmp];
        }
        self.lbl_item_descrip.attributedText = attributedText;
        
    }
    else
    {
        self.lbl_item_descrip.text = text;
    }
    
    [_lbl_item_descrip sizeToFit];
```

The below is my output

[image][image]

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: No I am not using auto layout. This is just a detail page so no use of auto layout

Comment: I tried using overriding UILabel also it is not working

Comment: please confirm that your string have no any white space. If yes then remove it. For remove white space pls check it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28571100/1746086

Comment: Hi @NilayShah My string does not have any white space. the answer link you shared is not working

Answer (score -1):

Can you remove `[_lbl_item_descrip sizeToFit];` after that try once.

Comment: Then multiple lines is not displaying