# Issue in removing spaces from string in swift

Tags: swift, string

i'm getting my contacts number locally from my mobile. There are some number in which there are white spaces between numbers. I'm trying to remove the white spaces from the number but it isn't working,this is how i'm removing the white spaces,

```
let number = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue
let formattedString = number?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
print(formattedString)
```

But when i print this is what i got in the console,

```
+92 324 4544783
The white sapces are still coming how can i remove that?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39067610/8417137

Comment: number?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

Comment: I have also tried this but still shows spaces in some numbers. @sazid008

Comment: clean build your project. because your code number?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")  seems correct also.

Comment: i have done that not working bro. @sazid008

Comment: please don't make it duplicate its an issue that i'm facing . I know that it is ask many times but not working in my condition. @vadian

Comment: paste your (number) value here. get that from debugger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179025/discussion-between-sazid008-and-hamza).

Comment: @Hamza It **is** a duplicate. Did you read all answers? There are answers to trim the string (remove whitespace from beginning and end) and removing whitespace within the string.

Comment: e.g. when you pick like phone # from Addressbook, there is some special char looks like space " ", but its not space. Try This
contact.phoneNumbers[0].phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

Comment: PS: In the special case of phone numbers the most reliable solution is `let formattedString = number.replacingOccurrences(of: "[^0-9+]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)`. It cuts everything out except digits and `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let number = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue
let number_without_space = number.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined()
print(number_without_space) //use this variable wherever you want to use
```

`joined()` is a function it will join your string after removing spaces like this

```
let str = "String    Name"
str.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined()
```

extension to remove spaces

```
extension String
{ 
         func removeSpaces() -> String { 
              return components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined() 
       }
 }
```

Comment: What is joined() in this, its showing me warning. @Mahnesh Dangar

Comment: @Hamza joined() function will join your string after removing whitespace check my answer i have updated it

Comment: Compiler is showing this warning Result of call to 'joined(separator:)' is unused. @Mahesh Dangar

Comment: @Hamza because you have to use the result of joined() function just a second i will update my answer as per your requirement

Comment: @Hamza check updated answer

Comment: //Remove White Spaces
extension String {
    func removingWhitespaces() -> String {
        return components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined()
    }
}

Comment: i have to make extension @midhun p

Comment: @Hamza no need to make extension if you want to use for this code for once or twice but if you want to use this code many times then extension will be best but both are work same

Comment: @Hamza check updated answer i have added extension so there is all possible ways you can choose any of them :)

Comment: Got it now it work fine thanks. @MaheshDangar

Comment: @Hamza your welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: [source](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-trim-whitespace-in-a-string)

For trimming white spaces from both ends, you can use:

```
let number = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue
let formattedString = number.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
print(formattedString)
```

For removing whitespaces that might be inside the string, use:

```
let x = "+92 300 7681277"
let result = x.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
```

You should get:

```
result = +923007681277
```

EDIT: I updated my answer.

Comment: I don't want these spaces as u mentioned in the answer. @Mihai Erős

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer... you should get the string without spaces. If not, can you post some examples of "numbers" that won't work as I mentioned?

Comment: Still, i'm getting spaces in some numbers. @Mihai Erős

Comment: Post those numbers. @Hamza

Comment: Optional("+92 300 7681277"), Optional("+971 58 292 7644") and many more. @Mihai Erős

Comment: @Moritz you are right, I updated my answer.