# get url from String using URL(string: ) constructor

Tags: ios, swift, url

I'm creating a function which makes an API request. 
The function receives a parameter and put it inside the API call.
It is like this:

```
static func queryCities(cityNameString : String, completion: @escaping (City)->()){
    let urlString = "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=\(cityNameString)&username=myusername"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
    print(url)

}
```

But only when I try to convert my String into a URL the function doesn't return anything.
I need to precise that the API call is working well if I paste it in safari.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your method does not send a request at all... It just parses the string and prints the URL out.

Comment: Yes I omitted the part where I did stuff because when I print out the url it doesn't print out anything and I want to know why is that. Basically it seems that the URL(string: urlString) constructor is not doing its job

Comment: Be aware that `URL(string:` returns `nil` if the city name contains a space character. Basically you have to (percent)encode the string

Comment: What `cityNameString` did you give it? By answering this, you are providing a [mcve], which helps us see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I found the solution by following this question

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `URLComponents` to assemble your URL:

```
static func queryCities(cityNameString : String, completion: @escaping (City)->()) {
    var components = URLComponents(string: "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON")
    components?.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: cityNameString),
        URLQueryItem(name: "username", value: "myusername")
    ]

    guard let url = components?.url else { return }
    print(url)

    // do the http request here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for space and remove it from `String`

```
 let cityName = "  My CityName  "
 let trimmed = cityName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found the solution for trimming here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570973/how-should-i-remove-all-the-leading-spaces-from-a-string-swift

Comment: This won't work either because it does not remove the inner space