# How to convert any textfield input to float in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to store float to CoreData and I want to convert every of the following inputs to 90.5:

- 90.5
- 90,5
- 90.5
- 90, 5

That means: Remove whitespace and convert , to .

Is this code best practice?

```
let str = "  90, 5  "
let converted = str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
let converted = strWithoutWithespace.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I remove all the leading spaces from a string? - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570973/how-should-i-remove-all-the-leading-spaces-from-a-string-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not because it doesn't remove the space within the string.

The regex pattern `"\\s+"` removes all occurrences of one or more whitespace characters.

```
let str = "  90, 5  "
let strWithoutWhitespace = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
let converted = strWithoutWhitespace.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
```