# Swift Google search with more than two variables

Tags: swift, search, textfield, nsrange

I'm trying to add a google search to my textfield. I've got it so I can look up one or two variables, but after three it crashes. What do I need to change or add to make it work? Here's my code...

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

```
    var urlString: String = textField.text
    var url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    if (url != nil) {
        url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/search?q=\(urlString)")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        self.webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
     if url?.scheme == nil {
        var spaces = urlString.rangeOfString(" ")
        var urlStrings = urlString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(spaces!, withString: "+")
        var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/search?q=\(urlStrings)")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        self.webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post all relevant information here, error messages, call stacks etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your `spaces = urlString.rangeOfString(" ")` is only finding the first space in the string, and so with a string that has more it will only replace the first space with + and none of the others. You need to use something more along the lines of:

```
urlString = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
```

Here we replace every occurence of the " " character with "+". So to summarise:

```
var urlString: String = textField.text!
urlString = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com/search?q=\(urlString)")
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
webView.load(request)
```

n.b. I've force unwrapped some things just for example purposes.

You'll also want to make sure that you trim `urlString` first in order to remove any excess whitespace (e.g double spaces, or spaces at the beginning and end). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963379/remove-whitespace-character-set-from-string-excluding-space-swift) for how to do that!

Comment: I've updated this to Swift 5 - if you can mark this as the accepted answer please @BethKnight, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Update for Swift 5:

```
var keyword = "Rhinoceros Beetles"
keyword = keyword.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
```

This should allow you to open the url properly.